# Drawing shadow with Quartz is slow on iPhone & iPad. Another way?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, quartz-graphics, shadow

I was pretty excited when I found out just how easy it is to add shadows to my UIViews on the iPhone/iPad.

Just add the framework in Xcode, add the import to the top of the file:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Then later:

```
self.contentView.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0;
self.contentView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-2.0, -3.0);
self.contentView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
self.contentView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
```

While this does create a beautiful shadow in my app, it also lags it to death now when the view is shown... even when launched outside of the debugger. Is there something I'm forgetting or is this method just not practical for larger views?

For reference, I posted a screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIWXr.png).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You should set the [`shadowPath` property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html). It is how CoreGraphics is able to optimize shadows.

For example, if your view is an opaque rectangle:

```
self.contentView.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.contentView.bounds].CGPath;
```

Comment: For those that get here from Google, though, could you change your "self.bounds" to "self.contentView.bounds" to match my example?

Comment: This helped me to fix a number of performance issues in my application at once. Huge thanks.

Comment: I would like to set a shadowPath for a CALayer that contains an image with transparency in it. In other words, not a rectangular shadow, but a shape that matches the opacity in the source image. Anyone have any idea about doing this?

Comment: Ah, I forgot about setting layer.shouldRasterize = YES, I think that will do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

Thought I should make an answer because I didn't want this gem to get buried in the comments.

In addition to cobbal's answer above, which helped a lot, occulus also mentioned the following optimization for non-rectangular shadows, such as text shadows.

```
self.contentView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
// Fix visual degradation when rasterizing on high-density screens:
self.contentView.layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```