# UIImageView - Why does adding a shadow slow it down?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drawing shadow with Quartz is slow on iPhone & iPad. Another way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677564/drawing-shadow-with-quartz-is-slow-on-iphone-ipad-another-way)

I created the below helper method to add a shadow to my UIImageViews. It looks good, but I noticed that it slows down the graphics rendering significantly and it looks especially bad when you rotate the device. I also get an occasional `Received memory warning.`

```
- (void)addShadowToImageView:(UIImageView *)imageView;
{
  imageView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
  imageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
  imageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
  imageView.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0;
  imageView.clipsToBounds = NO;
}
```

How can I optimize this effect for performance?

Comment: is this on a newer device?  I know older devices used to be really slow with CALayer but I haven't seen a noticeable slowdown on newer (iphone 4 and later) devices

Comment: How often are you calling this method?

Comment: Why don't you try building your project for Profiling, and then using the Time Profiler to see what uses the most of your CPU at one time?

Comment: Testing on an iPad 4th gen. Calling it 2-6 times in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check out this post:

[Drawing shadow with Quartz is slow on iPhone & iPad. Another way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677564/drawing-shadow-with-quartz-is-slow-on-iphone-ipad-another-way)

The gist of it is that you should be using CALayer's shadowPath property, as this is how CoreGraphics is able to optimize shadows. In fact, if you check the docs for this property, you'll see the bit

> Specifying an explicit path usually improves rendering performance.

As a general rule, directly manipulating the layer of a UIView (doing things like shadows or corner radii) tends to slow performance significantly.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I didn't know that shadows rendered so slowly. I'll keep that in mind moving forward.